# Bootstrap3 - Columns Touching

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I am trying to make a WordPress theme using bootstrap (i know not many people like this) and I am having a problem with building my grids up. The margin top is perfect, 10px. but the margin on the sides is incorrect and if I try to change it in CSS it drops onto a new row.
I am using 2 divs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8"><!--CONTENT--></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><!--CONTENT--></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lets say these 2 `col-sm` divs where block colours of blue. They are touching in the middle where i want them to have a 10px spacing.
The Code Below is not what happens it is a visual representation, so don't try and fix that code ;).

## Edit

I have now applied the below and my site looks like this, it is nearer but still not 100%
now it looks like this (the colours dont bother me its the sizes):

[ScreenShot](http://snag.gy/hH4ty.jpg)

style.css

```
.even_space > div > div {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px grey;
    border-left: 3px dashed grey;
}
.even_space > div {
    padding:0 10px;
}
.even_space > div:first-child {
        padding-right:0;
}

.main-posts{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Index.php

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="row even_space">
        <div class="col-sm-8 main-posts">
            <div>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
                <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
                <P><p><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>  in <?php the_category(', '); ?> <?php edit_post_link(__('{Edit}'), ''); ?></p></P>
                <hr> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
```

sidebar.php

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="sidebar">
    <div>
        <h2 ><?php _e('Categories'); ?></h2>
        <ul >
            <?php wp_list_cats('sort_column=name&optioncount=1&hierarchical=0'); ?>
        </ul>
        <h2 ><?php _e('Archives'); ?></h2>
        <ul >
            <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
        </ul>
        <h2><?php _e('Meta'); ?></h2>
        <ul>
            <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using fixed pixel width values with a responsive framework is always going to cause you problems.

Comment: I dont want to sacrifice responsive for such a small problem there must be a way :S

Comment: Bootstrap uses padding for gutters not margin. So you need to nest elements within columns rather than using the columns themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can do this using Bootstrap is use a nested container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8"><div><!--CONTENT--></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><div><!--CONTENT--></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And to manage the space you can handle the padding of the `col` elements wich is for default `15px` at each side.

Check this **[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/QH1HX0ggJ8)**.

Comment: I am looking at your demo and i can see it working but i cant apply it to my site for some reason

Comment: @Kieranmv95 this way is to hard to help U ... I can't know why you can't apply this answer

Comment: Added it to Question with screenshot

Comment: @Kieranmv95 yup I just see the Edit but glad to help U solve the problem mate

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use css to make the column smaller and then apply a margin like so:

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 64%;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 blue">CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT      CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 green">CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the percentage width, its still responsive. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xntcwfeo/) here.